# How to set FirefoxProfile with extensions for RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, remotewebdriver

I need to run my WebDriver tests on RemoteWebDriver with Firefox profile loaded with extension. My current code is

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
File firebug = new File("firebug.xpi");
File netexpert = new File("netexpert.xpi");
try {
    firefoxProfile.addExtension(firebug);
    firefoxProfile.addExtension(netexpert);
} catch (IOException e) {}
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(<<serverurl here>>, getDesiredCapabilities());
```

I get following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c187d01409a5dc3b7f8251859150c8af0bcb', time: '2013-04-09 10:39:28'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.5', java.version: '1.6.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

I do not get any error when I don't set the Firefox Profile and the tests run fine.

EDIT: On Removing the netexpert.xpi the tests are running fine. My standalone test was running fine with FirefoxDriver(not RemoteWebDriver) with netexpert enabled in same fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after I changed

```
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(<<serverurl here>>, getDesiredCapabilities());
```

to

```
WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(<<serverurl here>>, getDesiredCapabilities());
```

Comment: Hi expressions; to show that you've found the solution to your question, can you accept your answer? It'll take the question off the unanswered list.

Comment: @vincebowdren
I would have done that but can't do so before tomorrow.